# Pulling multiple records from Airtable into Google Sheets via Zapier

Tags: google-sheets, zapier, airtable

Wondering if there's a way to pull multiple records from Airtable into a Google Sheet via Zapier based on a conditional Y/N column in Airtable.

Basically, I want to create a Zap that searches all the records in the table and any record with a 'Y' in the column is pulled into a Google Sheet.

Zapier have told me it's only possible to do this by utilizing Code by Zapier however my skills are pretty minimal so I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction as to how I'd achieve this or if there's anything existing on Stackoverflow (I've had a search but can't see anything).

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: do you want this to be a 1 time import or an ongoing zap?

Comment: Hey @xavdid looking for it to be an ongoing zap that would run once a day.

Comment: Oh, once a day is a little tougher. the easiest version is "new record in view" -> create new row in google sheets. if you want it to be daily, you'd probably mix in a digest with a daily release and a code step to fan out. This is totally doable, the code step trick is a hack that is hard to debug. does it need to be daily or can it be continuous?

Comment: @xavdid it doesn't have to be once a day, it could be continuous. 

As it wouldn't always be a new record (the 'Y' could be added to an existing record) I created a Zap process of: 
1# Zap Trigger (schedule by Zapier on once a day) -> 2# Find record (searches for the 'Y' in a nominated field)  -> #3 created Google Sheets Worksheet -> #4 Create Spreadsheet Row -> #5 Send email

The issue i was having is that when it finds the record in step #2 it only looks for one instance of 'Y' when there will like be multiple records with 'Y' added to exisiting records. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Based on your comments on the original question, running daily is the requirement that's making this much more complicated. Given that you said the zap can run continuously, I recommend the following setup:

First, [Create a view](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/202624989-Guide-to-views#create_new_view) that filters for records that have all the properties you want ('Y' in a certain field, etc). The zap will look for new records in this view, so it'll work even if 'Y' is added to an existing record. The zap is as follows:

1. Trigger - Airtable: New Record in View
2. Action - GSheets: Create Worksheet
3. Action - GSheets: Create Spreadsheet
4. Action - Email: Send Email

I'm not sure what sort of volume or pattern you're expecting, but I would probably add a field to Airtable like "email sent". Then, add a step 5 to update the airtable row that clears rows out of the view to help avoid [this bug](https://zapier.com/help/airtable/#a-row-was-added-to-my-airtable-view-but-its-not-triggering-my-zap). That's optional though. It really depends on if you're going to be adding 'Y' to records that aren't in the 200 most recently created in the view.

Comment: Thanks very much, David. 
'New record in view' worked a treat! I hadn't even considered that as an option but it opens up a whole new world now. Legend!